# How to map a column of Output Data to another output data in TALEND

Tags: data-migration, talend

I have a situation where i need to insert the data from old DB to new DB. e.g.
In my old DB, i need to migrate USER_NAME, ADDRESS to my new DB tables, one in which there are two columns one is USER_ID which is auto generated and other is USER_NAME and in second table i have column as OID,USER_ID,ADDRESS. Now i am not able to map USER_ID to my second table.

```
OLD DB                            NEW DB TABLE A          NEW DB TABLE B
OID                               USER_ID ---------------  USER_ID
USER_NAME ----------------------- USER_NAME                OID
ADDRESS -------------------------------------------------   ADDRESS
```

Someone please hep me in doing this. I am not able to get anything on this.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using tMap, design job like below.

```
oldDbInput---main---tMap-----out1---newDbOutput_a----thashouput
                     |
                     |-----out2--tMap---newDbOutput_b
                                  |---thashInput
```

Map required columns from source to destination